# Xamarin.Forms iOS message is rendered BEHIND open popups. How can I set the z axis of a view?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using this custom component to show messages on iOS (kinda like a toast in android).

In android the toast is always rendered on top, but on iOS, if a popUP is open, the message is rendered behind the layout:

```
    void ShowAlert(string message, double seconds)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            alertDelay = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(seconds, (obj) =>
            {
                dismissMessage();
            });
            alert = UIAlertController.Create("", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
            window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
        });
    }
```

How can I set the z axis of a view so that it will be page -> popup -> message.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to achieve it by creating a custom "popup" UIView.

Just define a custom UIView to show the "Alert", then the toast will shown topmost.

MyPopupView class:

```
class MyPopupView : UIView
{
    public MyPopupView(string message, string buttonText)
    {
        this.Frame = new CGRect(50, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 2 - 30, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 100, 80);
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 8;
        this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(230, 230, 230);

        UILabel label_Message = new UILabel();
        label_Message.Text = message;
        label_Message.Frame = new CGRect(20, 10, 200, 20);
        UIButton button_OK = new UIButton();
        button_OK.SetTitle(buttonText, UIControlState.Normal);
        button_OK.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Red, UIControlState.Normal);
        button_OK.Frame = new CGRect(this.Bounds.Width / 2 - 30, this.Bounds.Height / 2 + 10, 60, 20);
        button_OK.TouchUpInside += Button_OK_TouchUpInside;

        this.AddSubview(label_Message);
        this.AddSubview(button_OK);
    }

    private void Button_OK_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }
}
```

Add MyPopupView:

```
MyPopupView myPopupView = new MyPopupView("A message here!", "I know");
this.View.AddSubview(myPopupView);
```

FWIW, In my test I used [Toast.iOS](https://github.com/andrius-k/Toast).